# Event on sortable item dragged over

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a unsorted list with sortable list items. I'm looking for an event or function to detect when a sortable items is being dragged over an item, that isn't part of the sortable items, for example a div.
Code I'm using:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item #1</li>
    <li>Item #2</li>        
    <li>Item #3</li>
    <li>Item #4</li>
</ul>
<div id='detection div'></div>
```

Jquery sortable:

```
    $("ul").sortable({
        placeholder : "ui-state-highlight",
        tolerance : "pointer",
        cursor : "move"
    });
```

So I'm looking for an event or function which detects when an list item is dragged over the detection div.

Thanks in advance,
Simon

Comment: Replace `div` with `li` and everything will become simpler and valid.

Comment: Changed the code to valid html

Comment: Maybe you need draggable?

Comment: But will I still be able to sort my list items if I use draggable?